# Read all file from selected directory MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a MVC project.

I would like to select a directory, get all file from some type, modify the files and write them to another location.

If you use  you can't get the path of the file because of security reasons.

Is it possible to read all the file at ones and sent them to my controller

Comment: For obvious security reasons , your asp.net application won't have access to the file system and modify files

Comment: So I can't write a web bases app?

Comment: Do you mean a file on the users PC?  If you absolutely need to do this, you'll need to write a plug in and that user must install it.

Comment: The files are located on a server (in office). And we need to added extra data to the files.

Comment: I have a similar program, that uses <script runat="server">. This is working but I would like to do this in a MVC enviroment, and there I'm stuck

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker: You can read files on the server the ASP.NET process has permission to access just fine. On your own server this can potentially be all files.

Comment: @KrisMartele: ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms both run on the same runtime and platform and you should be able to use the exact same code to read and write files.

Comment: You can use string path = Server.MapPath(file.Filename);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use virtual directories:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172138

You need this to point at directories outside your web application's root, and apply your code accordingly. Here's a tutorial on how to use virtual directories on IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Looks great. Thanks for the response